# Maven Shade Plugin How does it resolve multiple versions of same dependency?

Tags: maven, maven-shade-plugin

I am using shade plugin to create the uber jar. My pom refers to two dependencies which in turn have transitive dependencies of the same jar but with different versions. One refers to jsoup-1.7.3 and another refers to an older version.
Will the shade plugin ensure that the latest version of jsoup is used?

Comment: pretty sure its "last write wins", so it could end up with either/or. This is the problem I'm having at the moment.